# Where is the documentation for jssPreset in this CodeSandbox? I didn't find it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

```
import { jssPreset, StylesProvider, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Where is the documentation for jssPreset in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3lvcz)?  I don't know what that means. I wanted to check the document, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is currently any documentation specifically on `jssPreset`, though the [JSS plugins documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#jss-plugins) shows an example of using it.

When something isn't explicitly documented, the next place to look is the source code. Looking at the [jssPreset source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.2/packages/material-ui-styles/src/jssPreset/jssPreset.js), you'll find that this returns a JSS configuration object that includes all the JSS plugins used by Material-UI.

If you look for usages of it, you'll find it used to [create the default JSS instance](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.2/packages/material-ui-styles/src/StylesProvider/StylesProvider.js#L9).

The sandbox you linked to contains the following code:

```
import jssTemplate from 'jss-plugin-template';

const jss = create({
  plugins: [jssTemplate(), ...jssPreset().plugins],
});

function StringTemplates() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      <Child />
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

This is using `jssPreset` to get the default set of plugins included in Material-UI, and then adding one more plugin to the list (`jssTemplate`), then specifying to use that new JSS configuration via `StylesProvider`.

You can find the list of available JSS plugins in the JSS documentation: https://cssinjs.org/plugins?v=v10.0.0#jss-plugins.